# Generating CSV table from jinja rendered html template - how do I pass a python class object?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to build a simple flask web app that:
A) searches a small postgres database with a keyword
B) returns all relevant entries
C) renders entries to browser
D) user can download entries into a csv file

I am struggling to pass the python object from the jinja template into a python function.  When I pass the object from the jinja template to the function, the object becomes a single-element per index string and no longer has attributes `result.operation_name` and `result.project_num` .  I used

`<a href="{{ url_for('core.downloadsearch',result=result) }}">Download Search</a>`

to pass the object `result`.

This is a problem because I would like to use the attributes of the object `result` to divide the different variables into separate cells of the CSV.

Alternatively, I passed the query through the jinja rendered html to the csv-generating python function - it worked, however, I don't like querying the database twice for a single task.  It does not feel efficient.

***How can I successfully pass a python object from jinja to a python function without converting it into a string?  Or is there a completely different flow of data that is better?***

Below is the code:

Setting up the db.Model:

```
class ProjectInfo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'project_info'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, server_default=db.FetchedValue())
    operation_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    project_num = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __init__(self, operation_name, project_num):
        self.operation_name = operation_name
        self.project_num = project_num

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.operation_name},{self.project_num}"
```

Querying the database and passing to jina2 template list.html:

```
@core.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
       search_word = form.search.data
       result = ProjectInfo.query.filter(ProjectInfo.operation_name.contains(search_word)).all()
       return render_template('list.html', result=result)
```

In jinja rendered list.html, render `results` content and pass on to downloadsearch (csv generationg function):

```
{% block content %}
<div>
  <h3>
    <a href="{{ url_for('core.downloadsearch',result=result) }}">Download Search</a>
  </h3>
<table>
<tbody>
 {% for row in result %}
  <tr><td>{{row.operation_name}}</td><td>{{row.project_num}}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Generate csv file in python function:

```
def downloadsearch(result):
    #result is now a single-element indexed string
    #take result input and generate some csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, `url_for` will build an URL, so the data you can pass to it will be in the URL, your object will not be serialized to fit in the URL.

From my point of view, it would be more logical to pass the `search_word` to your endpoint `downloadsearch` and to get the results from there.

Moreover, passing `result` directly imply that you trust the client and client should never be trust for security reason, so additionally, you would have to verify the data sent by the client.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Can you elaborate on the security risk of passing result?  Is the danger that the client has an opportunity to manipulate the result in html and then pass an altered result into the downloadsearch function?

Comment: Yes it is. Client can send absolutely anything, you can't have control over it, so all inputs must be always verified on server side.